# Need help in audio recording

Tags: android

I am developing an application for audio recording. I would like to record audio with 30 seconds only.

How can I set the duration for recording audio and automatically play button goes to stop button while audio clip playing end? How can I implement this in my application?

Comment: http://rehearsalassist.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rehearsalassist/android/trunk/src/urbanstew/RehearsalAssistant/RehearsalAudioRecorder.java?view=markup

Answer (score 1):

you can use setMaxDuration (int max_duration_ms) of MediaRecorder

It sets the maximum duration (in ms) of the recording session. Call this after setOutFormat() but before prepare(). After recording reaches the specified duration, a notification will be sent to the MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener and recording will be stopped.

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
recorder.setMaxDuration (DURATION)
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Comment: @Thanks for your reply,i used this code,but I got exception from this line recorder.setMaxDuration (30)

Comment: the function accepts time in milliseconds. So try using:

    recorder.setMaxDuration(30000); //30 seconds